# What is a Bamboo shoot called in Hindi?

Tags: indian-cuisine, language

I haven't seen these things in the markets here. How do I ask for them in the local market?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language issues. I think this can be solved with Google Translate or even Wikipedia.

Comment: @Mien For what is the "translation" tag then for?

Comment: To be deleted? :P No idea, I didn't see your other questions till now, and I don't know if they are on-topic... I think this tag is meant if you have a very specific term in a language. To me, 'bamboo shoot' is rather universal. But I'll let the mods decide.

Comment: @Mien - This is a question of cuisine, and not necessarily language! Culinary terms are fair game here, and this is a question about regional culinary terms, as a simple translation, "baans", may not give the questioner an edible ingredient from a local market in India.

Comment: Especially in light of your answer, @RISwampYankee, I certainly would *not* vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

"Baans" (बांस) is the Hindi word for bamboo - there does not appear to be one for the edible shoot. Instead, there are a number of words used in Indian cuisine for bamboo shoots, depending on region.

> In Mizoram, they are called '**Mau Tuai/Raw Tuai**'. In Manipur, the fresh
>   bamboo shoots are called '**Uusoi**' and the fermented bamboo shoots are
>   known as "**Soibum**". In Nagaland they are called **bas-tanga**. In Assam,
>   they are referred to as **gaz** and in Nepal as **tama** (Nepali: तामा). In
>   western orissa region of India, people call it **kardi** and it is the
>   most famous dish there. In Jharkhand, they are known as **sandhna**

Wikipedia article on [Bamboo Shoots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_shoot#Local_names).

> Bamboo shoot tips are called salad or simply sunjian in Chinese and
>   juk sun in Korean, mang in Vietnamese, take no ko in Japanese, **gaz** in
>   Assam, tama in Nepal and **kardi** in western orissa. Bamboo shoots are
>   eaten in Goa usually during the monsoon season and are commonly known
>   as **Kill**. Bamboo shoots are used in preparing curries and pickle in the
>   state of Jharkhand, India. In Western Orissa or the Kosal region of
>   India, it is a common ingredient. Since this region is dominated by
>   the tribal population, bamboo shoots (or “**kardi**” as it is known), is
>   believed to have been in use for hundred of years. In this region,
>   “kardi achar” (pickled bamboo shoots) and “kardi baja” (fried bamboo
>   shoot strands) are also popular.

["Bamboo Shoots"](http://www.vahrehvah.com/indianfood/bamboo-shoots/) - by Sanjay Summa on the Vah Reh Vah site.

> **Keerl** (bamboo shoots) is something you will either love or hate.

["Keerl Ani Moog Sukho"](http://www.ruchikrandhap.com/2011/11/keerl-ani-moog-sukho-bamboo-shoots.html) - by Shireen Sequeira on her Ruchik Randhap blog, devoted to Mangalorean cuisine.

**Kalale** and **Kanile** are the names given by the [Bhakshya Bhojana](http://bhakshyabhojana.blogspot.in/2009/05/vegetables-and-fruits.html) blog.

Comment: thankful to you, but you haven;t told me what does it get called in north india. Moreover if I ask for "baans" in the grocery shop, they might think I am crazy!